# Find the minimum of $\max($area of any of $3$ parts of a right triangle$)$

Tags: geometry

> Let $\triangle ABC$ be a right triangle with $BC=AC=1$. Let $P$ be any point on $AB$. Draw perpendiculars $PQ$ and $PR$ on $AC$ and $BC$ respectively from $P$. Define $M$ to be the maximum of the areas of $\triangle BPR$, $\triangle APQ$, and rectangle $PQCR$. Find $\min(M)$.

I tried to find $M$ but couldn't do it.

[image]

edit: Original Question

Comment: could you share what have you tried so far?

Comment: @alphaomega yes, I've shared it.

Comment: You don't need $y$ since you have the angles and the hypotenuse.

Comment: Note that $x+y=1$, so the areas are $\dfrac{1}{2}\,x^2$, $\dfrac1{2}\,(1-x)^2$, and $x(1-x)$.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Let $x= \angle PCB$. Then, $PR = \frac1{1+\cot x}$, $PQ = \frac1{1+\tan x}$ and the areas are respectively,

$$[APQ]= \frac1{2(1+\tan x)^2}, \>\>\>
[BPR]= \frac1{2(1+\cot x)^2} \>\>\>
[PQCR]= \frac1{(1+\tan x)(1+\cot x)}$$

Due to the symmetry, the minimum of the maximum among the three areas above is when
$[BPR] = [PQCR]$ or $[APQ] = [PQCR]$. Use the former to establish

$$\text{min}(M)= \frac1{2(1+\cot x)^2}= \frac1{(1+\tan x)(1+\cot x)}$$

Solve to get $\cot x =\frac12$ and $\text{min}(M)= \frac29$.

Answer (score 0):

> Let $\triangle ABC$ be a right triangle with $BC=AC=1$. Let $P$ be any point on $AB$. Draw perpendiculars $PQ$ and $PR$ on $AC$ and $BC$ respectively from $P$. Define $M$ to be the maximum of the areas of $\triangle BPR, \triangle APQ, \sqsubset \! \sqsupset PQCR$. Find $\min(M)$.

[image]
Let $BP=x$, then all you have to find is the minimum of the vaguely angular curve $XYZ$ sitting on the top of all in $x\in[0,\sqrt2]$. That is, find which one of $Y$ or $Z$ is lower by finding the intersection of the curves.
[image]

Check answer: $\frac29$

Answer (score 0):

I am getting the answer as $\frac29$ based on boundary conditions.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/75xvF.jpg]

Hope this helps!

Comment: why isn't the image I uploaded isn't uploading!!?

Comment: thanks for the edit @Toby Mak ,

Comment: @tobymak, can you please why wasn't my answer(i.e the photo) uploading previously?

Comment: -@AMIT ASH, typeset mathematical terms using MathJax rather than posting image. [Here's the tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: ya, sure,
and I even answered some questions just now using MathJax,
but @SarGe can you please say why isn't the photo not uploading?

Comment: @AMITASH, it has already uploaded.

Comment: no sir,initially the link was only visible

Comment: but later @tobymak edited it, I want to know how did he do that, SarGe

Comment: @AMITASH, I guess you didn't put the `!` before `[ ]`. [Read this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-post) for more information.

Comment: thank you very much for your concern sir @SarGe

Comment: The equation of AC is $x+y=1$.